# php y sql server cade de conexion

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp

Tengo un archivo que debera contener la conexion a la base de datos(database.php) y tengo otro archivo donde realize la conexion con exito (testconnection.php) entonces necesito adaptar lo del archivo testconnection al archivo que utilizare en produccion.
Pueden apoyarme a realizarlo?

db_config.php

```
<?php
define('DB_USER', "u837223936");
define('DB_PASSWORD', "9dpyeQjs"); 
define('DB_DATABASE', "u8372239"); 
define('DB_SERVER', "ssqlexpress"); 
?>
```

Database.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

require_once 'db_config.php';


class Database
{
    private static $db = null;
    private static $pdo;

    final private function __construct()
    {
        try {
            self::getDb();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
        }


    }
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$db === null) {
            self::$db = new self();
        }
        return self::$db;
    }
    public function getDb()
    {
        if (self::$pdo == null) {
            self::$pdo = new PDO(
                'mysql:dbname=' . DB_DATABASE .';host=' . DB_SERVER .';port:63343;',
                DB_USER,
                DB_PASSWORD,
                array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
            );
            self::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }

        return self::$pdo;
    }
    final protected function __clone()
    {
    }

    function _destructor()
    {
        self::$pdo = null;
    }
}

?>
```

testconnection.php

```
$serverName = "SQLEXPRESS";
$database = "nameDb";
$uid = 'usuariosql';
$pwd = '1234';
  try {
        $conn = new PDO(
            "sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database=$database",
            $uid,
            $pwd,
            array(
                //PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            )
        );
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        die("Error connecting to SQL Server: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
```